# In Hexo, publishing draft discards the `category` and `tags` info

Tags: hexo

I was using the draft feature.  After I thought the draft is well written enough, I tried to convert it into post, by `hexo publish`.

This command, however, seems to discard the `tags` and `category` information and use that of the scaffold.

#### example

I created a draft like:

```
---
title: My awesome post on hexo
category:
  - hexo
tags:
  - hexo
---
The content of this post
```

My `scaffolds/post.md` looks like:

```
---
title: {{ title }}
date: {{ date }}
category:
  - misc
tags:
  - untagged
---
```

After `hexo publish`, created post would be:

```
---
title: My awesome post on hexo
category:
  - misc
tags:
  - untagged
---
The content of this post
```

### Question

- Is it possible to stop hexo using the `tags` and `category` of scaffold and use that of draft when `hexo publish`ing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that attributes will be inherited from draft if it was not specified.

So, the solution was to remove `tags` and `category` attributes from `scaffold/post.md`

```
---
title: {{ title }}
date: {{ date }}
---
```